# How to build custom shaped ribbons like this using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build custom ribbons to show progress, using bootstrap.
Something like this (see image).
[image]

Don't know where to start. Here's some code:

```
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-2 progress-ribbons active">Step 1</div>
         <div class="col-xs-2 progress-ribbons">Step 2</div>
         <div class="col-xs-2 progress-ribbons">Step 3</div>
         <div class="col-xs-2 progress-ribbons">Step 4</div>
         <div class="col-xs-2 progress-ribbons">Step 5</div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.progress-ribbons {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-color: #F0F0F0;

    position: relative;
    height: 44px;

    padding-left:3em;

}

.progress-ribbons.active {
    background-color: #d5a6bd;
    color:white;
}
.progress-ribbons:after {
    content: '';

    /* positioning */
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: -1px;

    /* triangle */
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 21px solid transparent;
    border-left: 24px solid #f0f0f0;
    border-bottom: 21px solid transparent;
} 

.progress-ribbons.active:after {
    border-left: 24px solid #f0f0f0;
    background-color: #d5a6bd;
}
```

Please suggest the most effective way to solve this. I would prefer using bootstrap. If not, any other solution is also welcome

Comment: Check this out - http://leaddyno.github.io/bootstrap-nav-wizard/

Comment: Check this http://codepen.io/bencull/pen/CHqwn

Comment: please add these as answers, so that I can vote up